# For loop to anotate images with imagemagick from text file

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I want to simplify my Christmas card making process. I have already built a frame with some text, and I wanted to personalize each card with the recipients name by using `imagemagick` and some bash power. **But so far I'm failing bad** :(

This is what I tried at first:

```
for i in names.txt; 
   do convert -font Akaya-Telivigala-Regular -fill black -stroke black -strokewidth 1\
             -pointsize 190 -draw 'text 640,730 $i' chrisFrame.svg -resize 70%\
             greetings_$i.jpg; 
done
```

But it fails with `convert-im6.q16: non-conforming drawing primitive definition` i' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4300.`.

Seeing that imagemagick was trying to use `$i` as a primitive, I tried to enclose it in double quotes, as I would do if I was passing the names by hand:

```
for i in names.txt; 
   do convert -font Akaya-Telivigala-Regular -fill black -stroke black -strokewidth 1\
             -pointsize 190 -draw 'text 640,730 "$i"' chrisFrame.svg -resize 70%\
             greetings_$i.jpg; 
done
```

Of course it generated a beautiful file named `greetings_names.txt.jpg` with `$i` instead of the name.

The content of the `names.txt` file is nothing else than

```
John,
Jane,
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Comment: First thing I might try is swapping the double quotes for the singles and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

With the gracious help of @GeeMack and after correcting an error in the call of the `for` loop, the solution is this:

```
for i in `cat names.txt`; 
   do convert -font Akaya-Telivigala-Regular -fill black -stroke black\
              -strokewidth 1 -pointsize 190 -draw "text 640,730 '$i'"\
              chrisFrame.svg -resize 70% greeting_$i.jpg; 
done
```

Effectively, inverting the single and double quotes made the trick.

Please notice that it was necessary to change also the line

```
for i in names.txt
```

for

```
for i in `cat names.txt`
```

### EDIT TO ADD:

After @Jetchisel comment regarding why one should not use `for` to read lines out of a file, the correct code will be:

```
while read i
   do convert -font Akaya-Telivigala-Regular -fill black\
              -stroke black -strokewidth 1 -pointsize 190
              -draw "text 640,730 '$i'" chrisFrame.svg\
              -resize 70% greetings_$i.jpg; 
done < names.txt
```

Comment: See why you [DRLWF](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @Jetchisel thanks for your comment, see the edited version. Now I know why DRLWF.